# How to convert anchor tag HTML links to use @Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, html, razor

I'm working on a localization project and I need to convert an anchor tag to use the `@Html.ActionLink` instead.

I have this html helper:

```
@helper RenderIcon(bool condition, string @class, string title, string url, bool openInNewWindow = false)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        <a href="@(new MvcHtmlString(url))" @(openInNewWindow ? " target='_blank'" : "")>
            @(this.RenderIconSpan(@class, title))
        </a>
    }
}
```

I've come up with this:

```
        @Html.ActionLink(this.RenderIconSpan(@class, title), url, null, openInNewWindow ? new { target="_blank" } : null)
```

But I get this error:

> Cannot resolve method ... candidates are ...

If I need to provide more information please comment and I'll provide that. I've never converted an anchor tag this complex into an `ActionLink` and I'm not sure that the ternary operator is correct along with everything else I've done.

Comment: MVC default methods don't allow you to do like this. But a simple hack demo has been posted. You can achieve your goal also by some other ways. Please let me know if this trick not work.

Comment: What's wrong with `@Url.Action` like `... href="@Url.Action("index", "home")"...`?

Comment: @Max Poshusta is their any restriction use `Html.ActionLink`?

Comment: Hey I'm on my phone right now - I left the office early. Mehmood I'll read into the answer more in depth in the morning but I don't think there is any restriction and also @Alexei Levenkov I was toying around with Url.Action and the idea that using that may resolve my issue. Again I'll dig into these in the morning and post a reply. Thanks for all the input!

Comment: I spoke with a colleague this morning about it (who was out of office yesterday). Turns out someone had already created a method to do what I needed. I simply called that method after @(new MvcHtmlString(CalledTheMethodHere). Thanks for the answers though, I'm going through a whole ton of these conversions and I'm sure I can make use of these answers at some point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have nested elements using the out of the box `Html.ActionLink` functions.  You will have to create an overload which takes something like an `MvcHtmlString` and inserts it into the anchor.

```
public static IHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper html, IHtmlString innerHtml, string action, string controller, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);
    var tag = new TagBuilder("a");
    tag.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    tag.MergeAttribute("href", urlHelper.Action(action, controller));
    return new HtmlString(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

(from memory, so you'll have to work out some kinks I'm sure)

Answer (score 2):

Here is Hack (low and dirty) workaround in case you need to use ajax or some feature which you cannot use when making link manually (using tag):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("LinkTextToken", "ActionName", "ControllerName").ToHtmlString().Replace("LinkTextToken", "Refresh <span class='large sprite refresh'></span>")%>
```

You can use any text instead of 'LinkTextToken', it is there only to be replaced, it is only important that it does not occur anywhere else inside actionlink.